# C# - Get list of rows that satisfy condition in query join

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, join

I'm new to using queries inside C# code so i need a little help over here.

I have these 2 tables in my db:

```
public class ItemTPRetencionPMD
    {

        public DateTime? FechaAprobacion { get; set; }
        public int IdPedido { get; set; }
        public int NroPedido { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string CodigoCompania { get; set; }
        public string Retencion { get; set; }

        public ItemTPRetencionPMD()
        {
        }

    }

 public class ItemTPSalesOrdPMD
    {

        public string SalesDocument { get; set; }
        public string BriefcaseNumber { get; set; }
        public string MaterialNumber { get; set; }
       
        public ItemTPSalesOrdPMD()
        {
        }
    }
```

And i have another class that contains a list of ItemTPRetencionPMD and a list of ItemTPSalesOrdPMD:

```
 public class TrackingProductoPMD
      {
            public int NroPedidoBrief { get; set; }
            public long NroPedido { get; set; }
    
            [NotMapped]
            public List<ItemTPRetencionPMD> Retenciones { get; set; }
    
            [NotMapped]
            public List<ItemTPSalesOrdPMD> SalesOrds { get; set; }
    
            public TrackingProductoPMD()
            {
                SalesOrds = new List<ItemTPSalesOrdPMD>();
                Retenciones = new List<ItemTPRetencionPMD>();
            }
    
     }
```

Now, i want make a query that returns rows of the "TrackingProductoPMD" table, and i also need it to include both the "Retenciones" and the "SalesOrds" lists.
This query has left outer joins, so i can still get the "TrackingProductoPMD" item even if any of the lists ends up being empty:

```
 var query = from prod in dbBrief.TrackingProductoPMD
                        join r in db.ItemTPRetencionPMD on prod.NroPedidoBrief equals r.NroPedido into itemConRetenciones
                        from retenciones in itemConRetenciones.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join so in db.ItemTPSalesOrdPMD on prod.NroPedido equals Convert.ToInt64(so.SalesDocument) into itemConSalesOrds
                        from salesOrds in itemConSalesOrds.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { prod, retenciones, salesOrds };
```

These are the conditions in my query:

```
TrackingProductoPMD.NroPedido == ItemTPSalesOrd.SalesDocument
TrackingProductoPMD.NroPedidoBrief == ItemTPRetencion.NroPedido
```

**Here's the problem i'm having:** The "ItemTPSalesOrdPMD" and the "ItemTPRetencionPMD" tables can have multiple rows that coincide with the condition, but i'm only obtaining a single row in each of them. And they are being treated as single items instead of lists. I need to get all rows that satisfy the conditions i put in the query as lists.

**How can i modify my query to accomplish that?**

Comment: You can only join items that have common properties. ItemTPSalesOrdPMD has three properties that are strings that are not in the other items : 1) SalesDocument 2) BriefcaseNumber 3) MaterialNumber

Comment: I did, in my query i joined SalesDocument from ItemTPSalesOrdPMD with NroPedido from TrackingProductoPMD

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying tables with many-to-many relationship, you will have to write separate queries something like below. Then return a model with results from both.

```
var prodRetencionesQuery = from prod in dbBrief.TrackingProductoPMD 
    join r in db.ItemTPRetencionPMD on prod.NroPedidoBrief equals r.NroPedido into itemConRetenciones
    from retenciones in itemConRetenciones.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { prod, retenciones };

var prodSalesOrdsQuery = from prod in dbBrief.TrackingProductoPMD
                        join so in db.ItemTPSalesOrdPMD on prod.NroPedido equals Convert.ToInt64(so.SalesDocument) into itemConSalesOrds
                        from salesOrds in itemConSalesOrds.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { prod, salesOrds };
```

Comment: Wouldn't splitting this into 2 different queries affect performance? I was trying to do everything in a single query to make it go as fast as possible.

Comment: There shouldn't be any performance issues (compared to a single complex query) and moreover you can get rid of left join in both the queries (or at least in one of the queries).